# Could not able to see new files from checkout branch in git

Tags: git

I am doing a web project deployed with tomcat. Since, it is a team project, we are using git for version control. I checkout to another branch from master branch by using below command,
   "git checkout skin-changes". I deploy the project and see new changes in web.However, I couldn't able to  new files that are in skin-changes branch in my project. I want to see new files. Please give me a solution for this problem.

Comment: I have removed the `java` and `IntelliJ` tags because, fundamentally, your question is not about these things, but about `git`.

Comment: Your problem is not very clear to me, but it looks like you need to add your changed files to git stage using `git add <file>` command, commit using `git commit <message>` and finally push your commit to remote repo using `git push origin skin-changes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood correctly then your problem is

> I deploy the project and see new changes in web

So to get the changes in your local copy you have to try `git pull origin skin-changes`